# Notes field only for certain product types

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

In my shop, I have two different kinds of products.type items and my products have variants.

For one of products type, I would like to show the note field in the cart.

My product types are:

- products
- options

For product type options, I don't want to show the note field.

How can I set this up?

Tried this without success.

```
{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
<form method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateLineItem">
<input type="hidden" name="lineItemId" value="{{ item.id }}">

{% if product.type('products') %}
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Productsort"  name="note" value="{{ item.note }}" required>
{% endif %}
<input class="form-control" type="submit" class="button" value="Bijwerken"/>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like;

```
{% if product.type('products') %}
    code to show notes field
{% endif %}
```

See the product model docs here https://craftcommerce.com/docs/product-model

The note attribute *is* part of the lineitem model so you should be able to show it.

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/line-item-model#note

The following should work.

```
{% for item in order.lineitems %}
    {{ item.note }}
{% endfor %}
```

You could try naming your input field like so;

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Productsort"  name="item[note]" value="{{ item.note }}" required>
```

I'd need to test this though. I've done something along these lines but can't remember exactly what I did.

Comment: That is what was my first thought too. But the note element is in the cart.lineItems and maybe that is why it is not working?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were trying to do. You want to show a note that has already been added to the item within the cart view right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Actually, you're doing it right. Is the problem that the note isn't being stored or is it simply that you are having problems with the condition to show/hide the note field?

Comment: Problem with the show hide. Storing of data works fine.
When Adding that if statement, nothing is shown.